# Simple 301 ReDirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

I currently use this to forward my URLS. But I had an error and I need to forward all

```
/search/search-term/1/ >> /search/search-term/
/search/search-term/2/ >> /search/search-term/2/
```

the 1 and 2 are page numbers.
All page 1's need to be at the 'root' url.

For some reason my code isn't working.

This is my CURRENT to for all the pages to work.

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z\d][\w-.'\d]+[a-z\d]+)/([0-9]+)/?$  results.php?whatwhere=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^/([a-z\d][\w-.'\d]+[a-z\d]+)/([0-9]+)?$   results.php?whatwhere=$1&page=$2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before the other rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /(.*)/1/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  %1  [L]
```

Replace `[L]` with `[L,R=301]`  for permanent redirection